# How does using (RecordSet).EOF on If statements work?

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

I have these lines of code, from vb6 trying to migrate them to vb.net.
What´s the logic behind them?

```
RegFileHf.CommandText = "Select dayspassed from Config"
  Set UltHf = RegFileHf.Execute
  If Not UltHf.EOF Then
    someDate  = Date - UltHf.Fields("dayspassed")
  Else
    someDate = Date - 180
  End If
```

Does the If statement executes multiple time until end of file?
Does the else part comes in only when there´s no rows on my SQL query?

(Can you guys recommend good books to learn VB.NET so I can stop making newbie questions?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `If` statement is not a loop statement, so it will not execute multiple time. I think your code is checking if value is returned then use first row else use default value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EOF condition mean that you get in the end of data .. that mean no row return

So, if there's (a) rows it will fire -> someDate  = Date - UltHf.Fields("dayspassed")

If there's no row it fire -> someDate = Date - 180

Something like that ..

In VB.NET

```
 Dim query = "Select dayspassed from Config"
 Dim dc = New OleDbCommand(query, connection)
 Dim rows As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
 rows = dc.ExecuteReader

 If rows.HasRows Then
   '...... someDate  = Date - rows.item("dayspassed")
 else  
   '...... someDate = Date - 180
 End If
```

Book --> try Google to find

Comment: Well for books, in case you had read a book particular and consider it great material, I was trying to find a recommendation rather a simple title :)

Comment: truly, I'm VB6 migrator and I get more knowledge in internet (like SO) .. Learn step by step .. start from easy case. You can learn from every cases here .. Internet has MSDN or any other reference which more updated .. Good luck !

Comment: Also, most of the in vb.net you don't have to check .HasRows at all. You just say, `While rows.Read()`, and when there are no rows the .Read() method returns false.